# Could not find site error

Tags: multisite, customization

Hi I was trying to change the default site of our multisite wordpress, I tried to do this first at the admin by adding a new site and checking the checkbox for the setup of the home site, after that on wp-config.php I changed the constant:

BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE to 3 which is the id of the new site. now I'm seeing this error "Could not find site" I check the database and everything is there have also followed instructions from this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_a_WordPress_Network but still it doesn't work. Did I forgot something during the settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try this procedure:

1) Go in to Network Admin -> Sites and edit the site you want to BE the new 'main' domain so it's url is http://example.com (remove the subdomain or subfolder path totally). There's a checkbox to change site and home URL. Make sure that's checked before you hit save.

2) Change the define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1); to whatever you want. Save it, upload it. DO NOT CHANGE SITE ID, YOU WILL BREAK THINGS.

3) Go BACK to Network Admin -> Sites and edit the site of the 'OLD' main site. Edit it so it HAS a subfolder pathing. /edition2011/ or whatever you want. Make sure the checkbox is checked. Save it.

I didn't try though but it should work.